# Group values based on annotation

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, find

Suppose I have the following lists

```
a = (np.array([ 0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12]), np.array([ 2, 3, 4, 0, 2, 2, 3, 4, 0]))
b = (np.array([ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12]), np.array([ 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]))
```

Where elements of `a[1]` are between 0 and 4

My objective is to cluster elements of `b` in terms of elements of `a`. Given the example, the results would be:

```
c = (np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0]), np.array([ val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6]))
c = (np.array([val1, val6]), np.array([val2]), np.array([val3]), np.array([val4]), np.array([val5]))
```

This is because `b[1][0] = val1` and `b[1][5] = val6` reference to `a` annotation `0`, as `b[0][0] = a[0][3] = 5` and `a[1][3] = 0`, and similar for `b[0][5]`.

One easy way of doing this is:

```
c = [ [] for i in range(5)]

for idx in range(len(b[0])):
    ids = np.argwhere(a[0] == b[0][idx])

    for id in ids:

        inc = id[0]
        elem = b[1][idx]
        index = a[1][inc]
        #print(inc, elem, index)
        c[index].append(elem)

c = [ np.array(element) for element in c ]
```

Yet, I find it very simplicistic and not scalable. Is there any other way of doing this easily?

Comment: You shouldn't name you variable `id`, as it's a reserved keyword in python

Answer (score 0):

You have a pretty convoluted series of indexing you want to perform, is there a way to simplify what you're doing? If not, giving each element of each tuple a different name will at least make things somewhat more understandable.

But to answer your question, here's a one-liner that will give you the same list as `c` in your example:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([ 2, 3, 4, 0, 2, 2, 3, 4, 0])
b = np.array([ 0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12])
c = np.array([ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12])
d = np.array([ 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600])

e = [d[np.searchsorted(c, b[a == value])] for value in range(5)]
```

For each value from 0 to 4 (inclusive), the index of elements in `a` that match `value` are used into index into `b`. Then `np.searchsorted` is used to find the location in `c` of all the values selected `b`. Finally, these indices are used to index into `d`.

It's horribly unreadable, so you would probably want to do each operation on a separate line.